# What are the benefits of offering Water to the Surya Dev (sun) in morning?

Tags: surya

What are the benefits  of doing Surya namaskar? By surya namaskar, I mean  offering Water to the Surya Dev (sun) in morning?

Personally, I have given water to Surya deva  for  1 month and I'm not getting any benefit. I'm thinking it is a waste of time offering Water to the Surya Dev (sun). Is there any guidance?

Comment: Surya Namaskara is part of Yogasanas in which no water is offered, you are probably talking about something else?

Comment: In Arghya think you should hold  a container or at least water filled hands up to drop water letting sun's rays pass through water into eyes before 7-30 am or after 6-00 pm (because direct sunlight is blinding harmful), preferably body fully immersed in a pool or shower. There is a short reference in Aditya Hridayam iirc. The general Yogic posture of this name is undoubtedly quite beneficial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Surya Namaskar and giving arghya are different. You are talking about arghya i.e., offering handful of water.

It is generally believed that Sun likes offering of water through arghya. This offering is called arghya pradanam which is part of Suryopasana which is also a part of Sandhyavandanam ritual. People also offer arghya to the Sun god exclusive of Sandhyavandanam ritual also. [There are group of rakshasas called Mandehas](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14912/5212) who fight with Sun god and obstruct his path. The water we offer will help him and clears the way. Hence, you are helping Sun god.

Lord Surya bestows good health. [Matsya Purana contains following verse](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15621/5212)

> **ārogyaṃ bhāskarādicchedd**hanamiccheddhutāśanāt /

īśvarājjñānam anvicchenmokṣam icchejjanārdanāt // (41)

> **Health ought to be sought from the Sun**, wealth from Agni, knowledge from Isvara, and emancipation from Janardana.

And [a similar verse](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15619/which-scriptures-contain-the-verse-arogyam-bhaskarad-ichcheth/20852#20852) which gives the same meaning from Padma Purana

> O lord of kings, he would fulfil all his desires with little effort. One should seek knowledge from Sankara, **and (good) health from Bhaskara (i.e. the Sun)**. One should desire wealth from Hutasana (i.e. Fire), and position from Janardana (i.e. Visnu). One should seek Vedic (i.e. sacred knowledge), giving peace to all beings, from the grandsire.

So, you will be bestowed with good health in near future and blessed with long life. There is worship of sun in many scriptures like Puranas and Itihasas. Lord Rama got victory after worshipping Sun god through Aditya Hridayam. According to Saura Puranas like Samba Purana, Sun god is manifestation of Brahman or Brahman himself. He is called Pratyakshya Bhagavan meaning the God we see daily who nourishes the life on the earth. So, you will be benefited in many ways besides health too.

Do not stop worshipping God and keep up the faith. Be patient. The fruits will be awards gradually. It is not a waste of time.

Comment: "Do not stop worshipping God and keep up the faith. Be patient. The fruits will be awards gradually. It is not a waste of time." That is speculation and is not allowed.

Comment: Sun worship recommendation  in Matsya Purana or Padma Purana seems acceptable and not speculation.The same recommendation repeated now looks like a speculation or opinion about the same Sun shining right from Creation time. Where is our dividing line in time? We still need to learn a lot what drives a running Faith.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu It is not a speculation. I am not giving any opinion or any advice. I am giving a fact. Speculation is something we do not know. But what I said is something said in the Puranas. When rishis do tapas and worhsip gods, the are not immediately awarded. Nothing is done immediately overnight. I have given sources where sun worship is recommended. When I chant mantras which give me youth, do I become young in the next minute? Or do you mean  worshipping god is a waste of time?